# Dual Booting Ubuntu Alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

So I had Windows 7 and tried to dual boot and ended up writing over my Windows 7 bootloader, but I really wanna try to dual boot with Ubuntu. I now have Windows 8.1 and want to try dual booting with Ubuntu again. Is there anyone that could walk me through this? I don't wanna mess up again.

Edit: So i read up on wubi, it does not work on windows 8. I can install using it, but i cannot then reboot into, it doesnt do grub right or something.

Comment: Sorta. Theres a difference in 8 and 8.1 but this definitely shows me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly dual-boot.  Typically after installing Windows OS you have to rebuild the grub bootloader.

I install an Ubuntu Live CD and fire that up in Repair mode.  You will see an option there to repair grub.  Ubuntu does its thing and afterwards you get a menu to pick the OS you want to boot into.

Answer (score 0):

This works. In the grub, there should be a system setup, open that and choose the windows boot manager. That will open windows.

Comment: Im trying to install it in the first place, i dont know what im doing 100%

Comment: Ok. Once you get it downloaded, download rufus and make sure you have either a usb or cd with at least 3 gb of space. Open rufus and select the iso and device and start. When it is done, shutdown your computer and when you turn it on, spam your boot menu button. Most computers use either f10, f11, or f12. Then just follow the onscreen instructions. The only thing you need to worry about is the device you install it on and what option you choose.